# Hibernate JPA 2.1 very slow on createQuery()

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following function which should return all 2262 entries from my MS SQL Database.
But it takes about 10sec and this is for this small definitely result too long.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Object[]> alleGamsBasis() {

    Query alle =  em.createQuery("SELECT b.Level,b.Last_Name,b.First_Name,b.Begin_Assignment,b.End_Assignment,b.kombi FROM Basistabelle_gam b");

    return alle.getResultList();
}
```

I have no `@onetomany` or something like that annotations.

Comment: First of all you don't use JPA and barely Hibernate by requesting like that.
Maybe something like that could be better : 
`public List<BasistabelleGam> alleGamsBasis() {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM basistabelleGam ").getResultList();
}`

Comment: By the way, because you say "I have no @onetomany or something like taht annotaions." I assume you don't have any JPA annotation, it mean you don't use the JPA and Hibernate.

Comment: Have you tried executing the query directly on your database? How fast was that?

Comment: Saying something is slow would then require your debugging about why you think it is slow. You execute a JPQL query, which is converted into SQL and that SQL executed in the database. You haven't even posted the SQL. You haven't posted how long that SQL would take to execute. You haven't posted what those entities are that are involved in the query. So there is no way of providing educated comment.